# Postfix seems to ignore spam miltering for LMTP

Tags: postfix, spam, milter

I use SpamAssassin through a milter to check e-mail, but it seems postfix does not check local delivery (like contact forms). How can I force Postfix to treat all mail as 'foreign'?

Comment: Did you try setting the `non_smtpd_milters` option?

Comment: Yes, that is set as a 'copy' of the smtpd miltering. DKIM does work, the message is DKIM signed even though it never leaves the server. Still spamfilter headers are nowhere to be found.

Comment: One way to force it could be to send all mail to smtpd, like `-o content_filter=smtp:127.0.0.1:25` in `master.cf`.  To me this seems heavy-handed.

Comment: Yeah that seems to not address the underlying issue, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was not a Postfix issue. The `spamass-milter` plugin I use to pass e-mails from Postfix to spamc (Spamassassin client) had a flag set in its systemd file that made it ignore localhost (127.0.0.1).